# How to deploy gulp on production server

Tags: git, gulp

When building a website (for the sake of clarity an HTML/JS only website) I use gulp to compile and concat some files which are then placed in a `build/` folder.

The folder structure looks something like this:

```
├── assets
│   ├── images
│   ├── javascripts
│   │   └── app.js
│   └── stylesheets
│       └── style.scss
├── bower.json
├── build
│   ├── bower_components
│   ├── images
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── scripts.min.js
│   └── styles.min.css
├── gulpfile.js
├── index.html
├── node_modules
│   ├── gulp-module-1
│   └── gulp-module-2
├── package.json
└── README
```

If I include all these files in a git repo, all of my changes will be committed twice. That is: a change in `assets/stylesheets/style.scss` will also lead to a change in `build/styles.min.css`. However, if I decide to exclude the `build/` folder from the repository, you will need certain development tools on the production server (i.e. gulp, npm, etc.) This can sometimes be difficult when there's limited privileges on the production server. Obviously excluding the `assets/` folder is not an option as you will lose the source for your compiled files.

Therefore my question is: what is considered best practice to deploy this on a production server? Do you include the `build/` folder in the repo, do you compile the `build/` folder on the production server or is there a third solution?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Although not everybody might agree on what the best solution is for this problem, I think there is a third solution you have missed and that I would generally prefer. You can build all the files on your development machine, and then deploy the files that were built to your production server. That would usually only be a copy action.

This way you will not need to have any development tools on your server and you will not have build output in your version control system.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I though about this too and it seems a simple solution. However, I was wondering whether there are other git based solutions. Then I'll be able to use functions like Bitbucket's web hooks to automatically pull the new version. I know there are other ways to do this without using git, but just wondering.

Comment: @Diederik I think that in any case where you want to deploy using Git, you will run into either of your original problems by definition.

Comment: Revisiting this after a year and a half, I am going to mark this as the correct answer. This has proven to be the easiest solution. In my projects I usually have a `deploy` command set up which `rsync`s the `dist/` to the production server.

Comment: For people who want to go deeper than `rsync`, consider `ansible` (or chef or puppet) for a yaml based configuration to deploy to an inventory of host(s) (allows for syncing the entire machine state via `apt` _in addition_ to `rsync`'ing the folder