# How to properly deploy project on production server

Tags: deployment, dependencies, production-environment

I would like to raise statements regarding how properly deploy projects with multiple dependencies on production server.
E.g. my project depends on node (npm), ruby (for sass), composer, gulp etc. - things which are related to development process.

So, maybe a good idea is to avoid all those things on production server, and create a separate repository to hold there project in 'production-ready' state with all dependencies (e.g. vendor/ directory with composer deps), and push it directly to production.

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32097479/how-to-deploy-gulp-on-production-server#answer-32102502) answer it looks like I should build everything on dev or local environment and then copy files to production, which might be tedious and maybe it would be good to hold everything in separate repository.

Or, are there already some best practices regarding this? Could somebody help me with the decision?

Thanks!